# Manage array from get request using useEffect and useState hooks in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help in managing some values from a GET request that returns me an array of values from reading a file inside the server.
When loading the functional component I want send the request so I'm using useState and useEffect in my code like the following:

```
import { useHttpClient } from '../shared/hooks/http-hook';

...

const Settings = () => {
    const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
    const [loadedSettings, setLoadedSettings] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchSettings = async () => {
                try {
                    const responseData = await sendRequest(
                        'http://localhost/api/settings'
                    );
                    setLoadedSettings(responseData)
                } catch (err) { }
            };
            fetchSettings();
        }, []);
```

I need to do this to fill some inputs of my form with the values from the array I get from the request:

```
    return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
                {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner asOverlay />}
                <form className="settings-form" onSubmit={settingsSubmitHandler}>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col">
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                                        <p>Database Connection:</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                                        <Input
                                            element="input"
                                            id="hostname"
                                            type="text"
                                            title="HOSTNAME"
                                            placeholder="HOST NAME"
                                            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                                            errorText="Required."
                                            onInput={inputHandler}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                <div className="col-sm-12">
                                    <Input
                                        element="input"
                                        id="username"
                                        type="text"
                                        title="USERNAME"
                                        placeholder="USERNAME"
                                        validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                                        errorText="Required."
                                        onInput={inputHandler}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group row">
                                <div className="col-sm-12">
                                    <Input
                                        element="input"
                                        id="password"
                                        type="password"
                                        title="PASSWORD"
                                        placeholder="PASSWORD"
                                        validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                                        errorText="Required."
                                        onInput={inputHandler}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
    ...
```

If I console log:

```
loadedSettings.map(elem => {
    console.log(elem)
}
```

It returns me all values from text file as expected.
How can I put every value in each input box?

Thanks

Comment: you mean, you need to display input boxes that each of them will display the corresponding loadedSetting value?

Comment: Just display the value inside of each input from the loadedSettings array @yash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this `{!isLoading && loadedSettings && (` and transformed array into an object so I can add in my input elements `initialValue={loadedSettings.MYHOST}` ecc..

```
{
   "MYHOST": "value1",
   "MYUSER": "value2",
   ....
   ....
}
```

Here the jsx code

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
        {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner asOverlay />}
        {!isLoading && loadedSettings && (
            <form className="settings-form" onSubmit={settingsSubmitHandler}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <div className="form-group row">
                                <div className="col-sm-12">
                                    <p>Database Connection:</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group row">
                                <div className="col-sm-12">
                                    <Input
                                        element="input"
                                        id="hostname"
                                        type="text"
                                        title="HOSTNAME"
                                        placeholder="HOST NAME"
                                        validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                                        errorText="Required."
                                        onInput={inputHandler}
                                        initialValue={loadedSettings.MYHOST}
                                        initialValid={true}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group row">
                                <div className="col-sm-12">
                                    <Input
                                        element="input"
                                        id="username"
                                        type="text"
                                        title="USERNAME"
                                        placeholder="USERNAME"
                                        validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
                                        errorText="Required."
                                        onInput={inputHandler}
                                        initialValue={loadedSettings.MYUSER}
                                        initialValid={true}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            ...
                            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to render the form input elements inside the map function

**please let me know if this worked fine with you**

```js
return (
..
loadedSettings.map(elem=>(
          <Input
            element="input"
            value={elem}
            id="hostname"
            type="text"
            title="HOSTNAME"
            placeholder="HOST NAME"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
            errorText="Required."
            onInput={inputHandler}
           />
))
)
```

Comment: Hi Islam thanks, but not, this solution re-render the input element many times as the values are in my array @Islam Hanafi

Comment: I thought that was your goal, can you tell me what exactly do you want to do with the array?

Comment: I update my JSX code example. I've already the input elements rendered, I just want to give them the value taken from my array. Example: first input value => loadedSettings[0], second input value => loadedSettings[1]... Something like this, if possible

Comment: If you want this behavior try my solution and I think @yash gave you the same solution.

render inputs dynamically inside map function

Comment: Yes could be a solution, but every input has different behavior, like validation and many other props, I should fetch not only the simple values but an array of objects with all the features.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JUz9LrF.png this was the consequence of re-rendering the input in this way @IslamHanafi

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can just replace this section

```
<div className="col-sm-12">
  <Input
    element="input"
    id="hostname"
    type="text"
    title="HOSTNAME"
    placeholder="HOST NAME"
    validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
    errorText="Required."
    onInput={inputHandler}
  />
</div>;
```

with

```js
{loadedSettings && loadedSettings.map((setting) => (
    <div className="col-sm-12">
        <Input
            element="input"
            id="hostname"
            type="text"
            title="HOSTNAME"
            placeholder="HOST NAME"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
            errorText="Required."
            onInput={inputHandler}
            value={setting}
        />
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Hi yash, thanks. This solution re-render the input element many times as the values are in my array. I've already rendered the inputs elements. I just want to modify the initial value for each input when loading the component.